# best way to call a method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I have some problems and I don't know wath's the best way to resolve it.

I have do a method, and I would like to help this in two views : poi.views and track.index

The method :

```
@distance_a_to_b = Track.find_by_sql(
  ["SELECT
    ST_Distance(line::geography, pta::geography) +
    ST_Distance(line::geography, ptb::geography) +
    ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
        line,
        least(ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, pta), ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, ptb)),
        greatest(ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, pta), ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, ptb)))::geography)  AS dst_line
    FROM (
      SELECT
        'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1.457834243774414 43.597960902821576,1.462029218673706 43.59636807591895)'::geometry line,
        'SRID=4326;POINT(1.457994 43.598124)'::geometry pta,
        'SRID=4326;POINT(1.461628 43.596128)'::geometry ptb
    ) data"
  ])
```

I need to call this methdod in two views....

poi.show = distance bewtveen A to poi (point())

and

track.index = distance for each poi (point())

This method need 3 arguments :

a = start point ( query params) as a Point()

b = an end point as a Point()

and a linestring or merge linestring

How can I post this arguments to this method ?

As kind of :

```
 @distance_a_to_b = Track.find_by_sql(
  ["SELECT
    ST_Distance(line::geography, pta::geography) +
    ST_Distance(line::geography, ptb::geography) +
    ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
    line,
    least(ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, pta), ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, ptb)),
    greatest(ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, pta), ST_Line_Locate_Point(line, ptb)))::geography)  AS dst_line
  FROM (
    SELECT
    '@track.path'::geometry line,
    '@poi.lonlat'::geometry pta,
    'query: params'::geometry ptb
) data"
])
```

How can I post the variables from each view ?
How can I get the result from this method, from each view ? by call method ?

Table pois :

```
t.geography "lonlat", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"st_point", :geographic=>true}
```

Table tracks :

```
t.geometry "path", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"line_string"}
```

Tracks has_many pois
Poi belongs_to track

**Edit**

Following the advice, here's what I did

In poi controller (Just to define the datas) :

```
def index
  track = Track.friendly.find(params[:track_id])
  @pois = Poi.where(track_id: track)
  @track =  Track.find_by id: 1
  @poi = Poi.find_by id: 1

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
end
```

In poi model :

```
 def distance_along_track_to(poi2, track)
   distance_sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT
      ST_Distance(tr.path::geography, pta.lonlat::geography) +
      ST_Distance(tr.path::geography, ptb.lonlat::geography) +
      ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
        tr.path,
        least(ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry)),
        greatest(ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry)))::geography)  AS dst_line
      FROM tracks tr, pois pta, pois ptb
      WHERE tr.id = #{track.id}
      AND pta.id = #{self.id}
      AND ptb.id = #{poi2.id}
   SQL
   Poi.find_by_sql(distance_sql).dst_line
end
```

In the index view :

```
<% @pois.each do |poi| %>
  <div>
    <%= poi.name %>
    <%= poi.track_id %>
    <%= @poi.distance_along_track_to(poi, @track) %> %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

And now I have this error message :

```
undefined method `dst_line' for [#<Poi id: nil>]:Array
```

I don't understand why @poi = nil ?

Comment: Can you give a little more background: the track is in the database, right? Are both points given as coordinates or are those also stored in the database? Can you show us the datamodel?

Comment: All data are in database.
Points are geography and linestring geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `@poi1, @poi2` and `@track`, you can write your method as follows:

```
class Track  

  def distance_between_two_pois(poi1, poi2) 
    distance_sql = <<-SQL 
      SELECT
        ST_Distance(tr.path, pta.lonlat) +
        ST_Distance(tr.path, ptb.lonlat) +
        ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
          tr.path,
          least(ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, pta.lonlat), ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, ptb.lonlat)),
          greatest(ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, pta.lonlat), ST_Line_Locate_Point(tr.path, ptb.lonlat)))::geography)  AS dst_line
       FROM tracks tr, pois pta, pois ptb
       WHERE tr.id = #{self.id}
         AND pta.id = #{poi1.id}
         AND ptb.id = #{poi2.id} 
    SQL 
    Track.find_by_sql(distance_sql).first.dst_line
  end 
end
```

and then you could call it as follows

```
@track.distance_between_two_pois(@poi1, @poi2)
```

Not sure what the best api is? I can also imagine writing something like?

```
@poi1.distance_along_track_to(@poi2, @track)
```

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda.. but it's dont work. I think I'm nearby to the solution...
Could you look what I did in the edit above ?

Comment: Ah right, the `find_by_sql` returns an array/resultset. So we have to get the first element first. Adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda... It's great and exactly what I append :D Just a last question, how can I order by distance ? ;)

Comment: What do you need? Something like the 5 nearest poi along a track?

Comment: No exactly... I would like found :
all pois around a line between X km to Y km from A.
 For exemple :
all pois around a line(radius 1km) between (5 km to 10 km) from city order by dist asc

Comment: Maybe that is something for a different question?

Comment: Yeah, that's the next step, I was just answering your question. I needed this function to continue. 
Step by step...I'm working on that now. ;)

Comment: Sometimes people keep extending a question, so one has to keep extending the answer. In your case "finding all pois around a line between a distance" is too difficult to be just a simple extension. Also: now if you could get the sql query it would be enough, so it should be simpler to find an answer, no? If you are happy with my answer, you could consider accepting it.

Comment: Done ;) I'm sorry I thought I did. Thanks @nathanvda for your help ;)
How difficult is it to do the calculation I want to do?

Comment: Imho not too difficult, but I am also not sure I understand your question completely (pois/track/line/buffer) so if you write it down in a separate question we could discuss it there? If you link the question here it will be easy to find for me :P

Comment: The follow is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866972/scope-or-method-for-this-query @nathanvda... could you help me ? ;)